# SSIS - Package execution failed after deploying it with a different VS version

Tags: ssis

I am trying to deploy a package using a Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer Version 14.0.800.90, but when I try to execute the package through integration Services Catalogs I get the following error:

[image]

The SQL Server version of the destination server is this: 13.0.5149.0 - SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU1 and the ssis product version in the server is 13.0.1601.5

I believe the issue lies on the script component of the data flow inside the package, which in my VS version is higher that in the destination server.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I've found that just going in and out of the script component does the necessary fix.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, change the Target SQL Server Version of your project to 2016, then re-build it and deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed the entire solution and it worked.